# Link to page in category

Tags: categories, pagination

I want to link to an archive page in WordPress, so like:

```
<a href="<?php page( 2 ); ?>">link</a>
```

so if a for example a category page is shown, this link needs to go to the second page for that category.

Comment: use a pagination plugin like [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-visualpagination/) or t[this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paginate/)

Answer (score 0):

After a long search on the Web, I decided to take a look at the plugins @anjum sent, and found out this can be done through:

```
<a href="<?php get_pagenum_link($i); ?>">Link to page $i</a>
```